# I don't know how a Boolean function can return strings

Tags: c++, string, boolean

how this boolean function returns a+b>b+a? Is a+b>b+a something different? It would be appreciated if you could explain the concepts used in this boolean function.

```
bool cmp(string a, string b){
    return a+b>b+a;
}
```

'cmp' was used to sort elements in a vector

```
sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), cmp)
```

Comment: counter question: `int x = 42; int y = 123; auto b = x < y;` what is the type of `b` ?

Comment: Look at [some documentation on the `>` operator and its companions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison). What is the return type of all of these operators?

Comment: What makes you think this function returns a string? That is not the case.

Comment: Assuming `string` in your code is `std::string`,  it supports a comparison operators (`==`, `>`, etc) that return a `bool`.   `a+b > b + a` computes two strings (`a + b` and `b + a`) and returns the result of comparing them using a comparison operator.

Comment: If a is `"a"`, and b is `"aaa"`, this kind of comparison would consider them equal.  That's a bit strange.

Comment: If you had `string a = "x", b = "y";` what string are you assuming `a+b>b+a` would be?

Comment: @Eljay - More than strange.   It also means that `std::sort()` will exhibit undefined behaviour, since `cmp()` does not represent a strict-weak ordering.

Comment: The `cmp` function does not change the parameters.  No strings are modified by the `cmp` function.  The `std::sort` function will call `cmp` with two parameters.  The `cmp` function returns true if the value of the first parameter comes before the value in the second parameter.

Comment: @Peter: My spider sense has been tingling about that as well, but I haven't been able to nail it down. Is there a set of two or three strings that would demonstrate that `cmp()` does not satisfy strict weak ordering?

Answer (score 5):

```
bool cmp(string a, string b){
   return a+b>b+a;
}
```

Is exactly the same as

```
bool cmp(string a, string b){
    if(a+b>b+a)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

You don't return the string but the result of the expression which can only be a boolean.

Comment: how can a string appear in an `if` condition ? :P Nice explanation

Comment: It might also be useful to point out that due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `a+b>b+a` is equivalent to `(a+b) > (b+a)`. Perhaps that has something to do with the OP's confusion.